# How to automate dropping all tables and re-creating them

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

I'm making a .NET 6 application with EntityFrameworkCore, where I constantly find new bugs and I would like to automate the process of dropping all tables and re-creating them in my current SQLite .db file.

My tables are created with the `DbSet<T>` property in `DbContext` class. However if i wish to re-create them i need to manually click to drop all tables in my IDE (Rider), manually delete all migrations, go to the terminal and type `dotnet ef migrations add FirstMigration` and then `dotnet ef database update`.
Is there a way to automate this process with just C# code?

Comment: Why not delete the file and recreate it? If you drop all tables, all the data is gone anyway

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah i can do that but i still need to type `dotnet ef migrations add blablabla` in the terminal for the tables to get created again. Problem is if i just delete the file i need to add it again to the IDE sqlite explorer that allows me to view tables.

Comment: You can write small powershell script doing that, but I think unless you are doing this multiple times a day - you will spend more time automating this with code than handling manually - just delete the database file and folder with migrations and add needed commands to readme file so you can quickly copy-paste them.

Comment: @GuruStron since i'm on linux i can make a bash script for it but i was hoping to learn how to do it so that it works on different databases, since i plan to use other databases in other projects.

Comment: @Graf123456 You can try look into `EnsureDeleted` and seeding initial data - that is what I do with local SQLite databases for testing,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment from @GuruStron suggested `EnsureDeleted` seems to work, at least for SQLite. Provided that the `DataContext` below, extends the DbContext class, the code that works for me in `Program.cs` is:

```
var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```